# Use implicit differentation to find the slope of the tangent line to the curve $y^3+3x^2y+5y=3$ at $(-2,1)$

Tags: calculus

I would like to evaluate the tangent slope of

$$y^3+3x^2y+5y=3$$ at the point $(-2,1)$

So I got

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -6\frac{xy}{ 3x^2}+3y^2+5$$

Do I even need this to find the slope?

Comment: Now just plug ing $x=-2$ and $y=1$ to find the actual value

Comment: Umm... how were you planning to find the slope?

Comment: I believe that you plug in the points into the dy/dx. So I got 3/5 as the slope. Am I wrong? :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{6xy}{3x^2+3y^2+5}$ to find the slope by plugging in $x=-2,y=1$ in that equation.

When you plug in those values you get
$$=-\dfrac{6(-2)(1)}{3(-2)^2+3(1)^2+5}=\dfrac{12}{20}=\dfrac{3}{5}\mbox{ (which is the slope required)}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I just wanted to make sure I was doing it right!

Comment: Your welcome! ..

Comment: My edit was for a (trivial)  typo, a mis-spelling of "values"....+1